# Changing field type in elastic search 2.3.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a project using elastic search for indexing and query large data.
The automatic mapper created on of my fields as double and i would like to change it to int, i can of course do it manually but i have been trying to do it with put command on the index\type

What i tried is :

```
 PUT myindex/_mapping/model
 {
     "model" : {
        "properties" : {
            "programnumber" : {"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"}
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Once created, fields [cannot be changed anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings) (with a few notable exceptions)

If your `programnumber` field was created as a double, it's most probably because the value of that field in the first document you indexed was a floating-point value.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays ElasticSearch allows you to go around this.

Just change your mapping and then reindex.

As you can read from the answer to a similar question: [Change field type from string to integer? and how to re-index?](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/change-field-type-from-string-to-integer-and-how-to-re-index/28021)

> ... you have to reindex. You can do that with Logstash (example configs have been posted in the past) or third-party tools like es-reindex. After reindexing to a new name (e.g. the original name with an underscore appended) you can delete the original index and create an alias named like the original index that points to the new index. Thereby everything will work as before.

Interesting link: [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)